# Identify Observe-Drivers-Polling Queries in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor's `Facts` package on the client with oplog tailing enabled tells me I have 20 queries utilizing `observe-drivers-oplog` and 1 query utilizing `observe-drivers-polling`.  I'd like to identify the query that is polling.

The stats above are identified in the `{{> serverFacts}}` template on the client; I've also inspected `Facts` object in the client console, which contains a good deal of information but I'm not sure what keys I want to be looking at, if any.

I'd love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered using Kadira ? https://kadira.io/

Comment: For an specific answer, see this: https://kadira.io/academy/optimize-your-app-for-oplog/